# SQL - If exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are 2 tables: **subjects** and **messages**.

subjects table:

```
----id----   ----title----
1            Subject 1
2            Subject 2
3            Subject 3
```

messages table:

```
----id----   ----subject----   ----message----
1            1                 Message to Subject 1
2            1                 Message to Subject 1
3            2                 Message to Subject 2
```

How to get `mysql_num_rows` of **subjects**, which has got any messages in **messages**? The result must be 2, because Subject 1 has message in `messages`, and Subject 2 has message in `messages`, but Subject 3 hasn't got any message in `messages`.

Something like:

`mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects ...`

Comment: Where is your query ? What you have tried so far?

Comment: `select count( distinct subject ) from messages` I think

Comment: @OtoShavadze can we select directly from `subjects`?

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally use `in` or `exists` for this purpose:

```
select count(*)
from subjects s
where exists (select 1 from messages m where m.subject_id = s.id);
```

This can easily be modified to get the subjects with no messages.

If you have a proper foreign key relationship defined between the tables, then you can just count the subjects in messages:

```
select count(distinct m.subject_id)
from messages;
```

Aggregation in MySQL is quite expensive.  There are circumstances where this will perform better.  However, the exists`is likely to perform better under most circumstances, assuming you have an index on`messages(subject_id)`.

Comment: The `select count( distinct subject ) from messages` from Oto seem a better idea than the `exists` option for me...

Comment: why will `select count( distinct subject ) from messages` not work...out of curiosity and learning.

Comment: Oh, thank you, for your answer, it's the right answer, I needed selection directly from `subjects`!

Comment: @PrabhatG because I need to select queries from `subjects`, not from `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** I think we can simply do it using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT COUNT(mes.subject) total_msg
FROM subjects sub
INNER JOIN messages mes on mes.subject_id = sub.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT messages.id, messages.message, 
        subjects.title,subjects.id as subjectID
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN subjects
        ON messages.subject=subjects.id");
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    echo $row_cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for `title` in the `messages`, then try this.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/AKXKVI76904)**

```
select count(s.title) as result 
from subjects s
where exists (select 1 from messages m
                where instr(m.message,s.title)> 1
             )
```

Explanation: `instr(m.message,s.title)` will search for `title` in `messages` and return the start position (integer). If not found, you will get `0`. So `instr(m.message,s.title)> 1` will only be true for the expected matches.

Then `count(s.title)` will give you distinct count.